GDB -break-commands not work when attach a running process
GDB -break-commands not work when attach a running process
this is an example
c++
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>
#include <chrono>

int main()
{
    int i = 0;
    int m = 0;
    while (i < 100000)
    {
        i++;
        if (i % 2 == 0)
        {
            m++;
        }
        // sleep(1);
        std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds(1));

        std::cout << "m: " << m << ", i: " << i << std::endl;

        if (m > 100 && i == 100)
        {
            break;
        }
    }

    std::cout << "end m: " << m << ", i: " << i << std::endl;
    return m;
}

gdb command
gdb -p $(pidof ./test_condiction_breakpoint) --batch -ex "interpreter-exec mi '-break-insert -c \"m == 10\" -f test_condiction_breakpoint.cc:21'" -ex "interpreter-exec mi '-break-after 1 1'" -ex "interpreter-exec mi '-break-commands 1 \"silent\" \"set var m=1001\" \"set var i=100\"  \"cont\"'" -ex "interpreter-exec mi 'set follow-fork-mode parent'" -ex "interpreter-exec mi '-break-list'" -ex "interpreter-exec mi '-exec-continue'"

in this case, the gdb break commands is not working, can any one help me?

What does not working mean here exactly? Can you at least show the gdb output of the command?

It appears to work here:
$ gdb -v
GNU gdb (Ubuntu 12.1-0ubuntu1~22.04) 12.1

Note that debugging (-g) must be enabled for the breakpoint to work.
$ g++ -g t.cpp -o t
$ ./t

My Ubuntu requires sudo to attach to running processes.
$ sudo gdb -p $(pidof ./t) --batch -ex "interpreter-exec mi '-break-insert -c \"m == 10\" -f t.cpp:21'" -ex "interpreter-exec mi '-break-after 1 1'" -ex "interpreter-exec mi '-break-commands 1 \"silent\" \"set var m=1001\" \"set var i=100\"  \"cont\"'" -ex "interpreter-exec mi 'set follow-fork-mode parent'" -ex "interpreter-exec mi '-break-list'" -ex "interpreter-exec mi '-exec-continue'"
[Thread debugging using libthread_db enabled]
Using host libthread_db library "/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libthread_db.so.1".
0x00007f87a8ae578a in __GI___clock_nanosleep (clock_id=clock_id@entry=0, flags=flags@entry=0, req=0x7ffdb6318d60, rem=0x7ffdb6318d60) at ../sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/clock_nanosleep.c:78
78      ../sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/clock_nanosleep.c: No such file or directory.
^done,bkpt={number="1",type="breakpoint",disp="keep",enabled="y",addr="0x0000560c8d42b2ef",func="main()",file="t.cpp",fullname="/tmp/tmp/t.cpp",line="21",thread-groups=["i1"],cond="m == 10",times="0",original-location="t.cpp:21"}
^done
^done
&"set follow-fork-mode parent\n"
^done
^done,BreakpointTable={nr_rows="1",nr_cols="6",hdr=[{width="7",alignment="-1",col_name="number",colhdr="Num"},{width="14",alignment="-1",col_name="type",colhdr="Type"},{width="4",alignment="-1",col_name="disp",colhdr="Disp"},{width="3",alignment="-1",col_name="enabled",colhdr="Enb"},{width="18",alignment="-1",col_name="addr",colhdr="Address"},{width="40",alignment="2",col_name="what",colhdr="What"}],body=[bkpt={number="1",type="breakpoint",disp="keep",enabled="y",addr="0x0000560c8d42b2ef",func="main()",file="t.cpp",fullname="/tmp/tmp/t.cpp",line="21",thread-groups=["i1"],cond="m == 10",times="0",ignore="1",script={"silent","set var m=1001","set var i=100","cont"},original-location="t.cpp:21"}]}
^done
[Inferior 1 (process 1426754) exited with code 0351]

The program output is:
$ ./t
m: 0, i: 1
m: 1, i: 2
m: 1, i: 3
m: 2, i: 4
m: 2, i: 5
m: 3, i: 6
m: 3, i: 7
m: 4, i: 8
m: 4, i: 9
m: 5, i: 10
m: 5, i: 11
m: 6, i: 12
m: 6, i: 13
m: 7, i: 14
m: 7, i: 15
m: 8, i: 16
m: 8, i: 17
m: 9, i: 18
m: 9, i: 19
m: 10, i: 20
m: 10, i: 21
end m: 1001, i: 100

Is your source file really called test_condiction_breakpoint.cc ?
